# Unable to render partial view inside Custom Tag Helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1, razorengine, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I am trying to use the following code for a custom tag helper and believe this should work for a partial view that references the built-in tag helpers, for example "asp-for". However, it appears that the rendering is not working. Per this discussion it appears it should be: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5504

```
public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
    (_htmlHelper as IViewContextAware).Contextualize(ViewContext);

    var wiring = new WireupModel() { FieldName = this.FieldName, PlaceHolder = this.PlaceHolder };

    var content = await _htmlHelper.PartialAsync("~/Views/Shared/_EditControlTemplate.cshtml", wiring);
    output.TagName = "div";
    output.Attributes.SetAttribute("class", "col-12 col-sm-6 form-group mb-3");
    output.Content.SetHtmlContent(content);
}
```

One of the html elements in the partial view is a label that looks like this:

```
<label asp-for="@Model.FieldName" class="control-label"></label>
```

However, this gets rendered as follows:

```
<label class="control-label" for="FieldName">FieldName</label>
```

At runtime, I stepped into the razor code in the partial view and the value is correctly coming in from the model as "FirstName" not as "FieldName".

My goal is to reduce lots of duplicate html by replacing it with a custom tag like so:

```
<edit-control field-name="FirstName" place-holder="@SharedLocalizer["First Name"]"></edit-control>
```